# How to get the pre-ordered weapons

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I got Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare but I didn't got the Day Zero edition that was giving some weapons for those who would pre-order the game. What I'm wondering is if I can get those weapons now that I have the game already without it being pre-ordered.

Comment: They are pretty much just gold versions of existing weapons, no benefits to stats or anything special like that. So I wouldn't worry about it to be honest

Comment: The AK12 has a nice iron sights, but the AK12G has a really sweet iron sights. I mostly want it for that..

Comment: The AK-12 G is tainted with the CoD Ghosts logo...

Answer (score 1):

> **No, that is currently impossible to get the per-ordered weapons like that.**

But, keep in mind these weapons are still in the game and fully obtainable , 
but you cannot get the special variants that are only for the per-ordered version.

**(examples: The AK-12G Assault Rifle and the Crossbow-B2)**

> The AK-12G Assault Rifle and the Crossbow-B2 will be included for all those who pre-ordered COD:AW. The base weapons are already in the game, but these are special Variants of the original weapons.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare/Pre-Order_Bonuses)

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand on Chantolas answer. For starters what platform are you playing on? If you are playing on a xbox than you should be able to access the ae4 assult rifle and its widow maker variant. Otherwise, by now you should have access to the bal27 atlas edition and a couple other guns but they are all cosmetic (they are just different looks to the gun)